# how to trigger an event when a row is deleted?

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason the code I am using does not seem to work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Delete = Target.EntireRow.Delete Then
Range("BP9").Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-65]='Trip Pad'!R1C2,1,0)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BP9:BP1071")
Range("BP9:BP1071").Select
Range("BQ9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+R[-1]C"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BQ9:BQ1625")
Range("BQ9:BQ1625").Select
Range("BR9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*RC[-1]"
Range("BR9").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BR9:BR118")
Range("BR9:BR118").Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Define "does not work".

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Each time the worksheet is changed, look at the number of rows.

```
Public lRowCount as Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws as excel.worksheet
Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

if ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count < lRowCount then
    'We have less rows than the last time the worksheet changed.
    'Do something here
end if

'Record the number of rows in the usedrange for checking next time
lRowCount = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

End sub
```

And set the lRowCount on workbook open

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    lRowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks mattd for your continued support. however this code seems to have no effect. would a method that counted rows really work (since it seems as though when we delete a row it is simply replaced)? or could this error  have something to do with the fact that I got an error when i placed "publiclrowcount as long " after the private sub line?

Comment: Public lRowCount as Long is a public variable. It should be declared at the very top of you module or form.  It should be above all sub, functions, and event code.

Comment: i put it at the top but it still seems to have no effect :"(

Comment: Did you put your code where i commented 'Do something here' ?

Comment: yes i put what i had in my original post beginning with range bp9.activate